# Que veut dire l’expression « de tradition » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Dans un texte anthropologique (*[Le sexuel et le social. Lecture anthropologique](http://classiques.uqac.ca/contemporains/balandier_georges/sexuel_et_social/sexuel_et_social_texte.html)* de Georges Balandier dans les *Cahiers internationaux de sociologie*) je trouve dans des phrases l’expression « de tradition » ou « de la tradition ». Que veut dire cette expression dans de telles phrases?

- > Le déclin du souverain africain de tradition, puis sa disparition, imposent d'opérer à temps la reprise de force - la force d'ordre et de fécondité…
- > Le roi africain de la tradition se situe, dans sa relation à la femme, de manière singulière. Ce que montre le rapport à sa mère, à ses « sœurs », à ses épouses…
- > La symbolique des royautés africaines de la tradition renvoie toujours aux signifiants de la puissance, dont celle du sexe. L'équivalent du roi est alors l'Étalon, le Taureau…

Answer (score 2):

"Le souverain de tradition" est un souverain qui tire sa légitimité de la tradition, contrairement par exemple à un souverain de droit divin qui tire sa légitimité du droit divin.

"Le souverain de la tradition" est un souverain tel qu'il est décrit dans la tradition.